# CSS styling placing an image within a div: display: table;position: relative

Tags: css

I have the following set to html and css and I would like to place an image in the colored boxes.
The sample code is in the link below -

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G1J7WQ8H7WPY

I am struggling with this. I need to put the image within the box. This is an existing website, and I have to add the image in those boxes.
Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: like this? https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G1J8LTI4A2QW

Comment: The buttons are now coming one after another - vertically, can we have them horizontally?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G1K1Z2JJSW9V

Answer (score 1):

You can set the div background as image instead placing image on it